# How to match 2 same strings with egrep separated with 1 or more spaces

Tags: regex, grep

I need to match 2 same strings separated by one or more spaces. Example:

foo   foo <-match
foo   fooo <- not a match

So far I have:

```
egrep '[ ]\w+[ ]{1,}' sample.txt
```

which matches only random string and any number of spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this `grep` with a captured group and a back-reference:

```
grep -owE '(\w+)[[:blank:]]+\1' file

foo    foo
```

**RegEx Description:**

```
(              # start capture group #1
   \w+         # match 1 or more word characters
)              # end capture group #1
[[:blank:]]+   # match 1 or more spaces or tabs
\1             # back-reference to captured group #1
```

By using `-w` option and back-reference `\1` we ensure we are matching exact same words matched separated by 1 or more spaces.